# Different output with printf

Tags: c, strtol

I am trying to print the value of a particularly large value after reading it from the console. When I am trying to print it from two different ways, one directly after assigning, one with the return value from the `strtol` function, I get different output! Can someone please explain me why I am noticing two different outputs?

Input value is: 4294967290

Here is the code snippet.

```
long int test2 = strtol(argv[1], &string, 10);
printf("the strtol value is %ld\n", test2);
printf("the strtol function value is %ld\n", strtol(argv[1], &string, 10));
```

Output

```
the strtol value is -6
the strtol function value is 4294967290
```

Comment: "PS: Pls point me if this question has already been answered. Thanks!" That is research you should already have done before you posted the question

Comment: The posted code looks ok to me.

Comment: To me it is the same. I think  there is a problem in other parts

Comment: I can’t reproduce this. Could you please provide a complete example? Are you sure `test2` is declared as a `long int`? It looks like it’s 32 bits and `long int` is more.

Comment: It coundn't be reproduced in [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/72bfWtPWEHUM05fG) and [Ideone](https://ideone.com/G4tsxZ). What is your compiler?

Comment: Are you compiling in an environment where long is 32 bit but linking with a library where long is 64 bit?

Comment: Frankly, I don't believe that's the output you see — or, if it is, then the code you show isn't the code you execute.  Which machine are you on?  Are you dealing with 32-bit or 64-bit code?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: it's easy enough to reproduce. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb9ae7594f8a8edb

Comment: @rici: 64-bit little-endian Unix system, and invoking undefined behaviour?  _[…time passes…]_  Hmmm; if you don't include `<stdlib.h>` then you're invoking undefined behaviour too.  Well, I certainly assumed that the code was being compiled under C99 or C11 rules — not under sloppy old C89/C99 rules.  Grrr!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: 64-bit little-endian Unix-like systems are pretty common, I think :) And you can tell gcc `-std=c99`; it will still just produce a warning or three. There's probably a canonical "you forgot to declare the library function" question somewhere waiting to be used as a dup... (There is no other UB in that snippet, is there? With the right includes, it should be fine.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things:

1. Add the line `#include <stdlib.h>` at the beginning of your program. That will cause `strtol` to be declared. (You also need `#include <stdio.h>` in order to declare `printf`.)
2. Add `-Wall` to your compiler flags (if you are using gcc or clang). That will cause the compiler to tell you that you need to declare `strtol`, and it might even suggest which header to include.

What is going on is that you haven't declared `strtol`, with the result that the compiler assumes that it returns an `int`.

Since 4294967290 is 2<sup>32</sup>-6, it is the 32-bit [Two's-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of -6. Because the compiler assumes that `strtol` returns an `int`, the code it produces only looks at the low-order 32 bits. Since you are assigning the value to a `long`, the compiler needs to emit code which sign-extends the `int`. In other words, it takes the low-order 32 bits *as though they were a signed integer* (which would be -6) and then widens that -6 to a `long`.

In the second call to `printf`, the return value of `strtol` is inserted in the `printf` argument list without conversion. You tell `printf` that the argument is a `long` (by using the `l` flag in `%ld`), and by luck the entire 64 bits are in the argument list, so `printf` reads them out as a `long` and prints the "correct" value.

Needless to say, all this is undefined behaviour, and the actual output you are seeing is in no way guaranteed; it just happens to work that way with your compiler on your architecture. On some other compiler or on some other architecture, things might have been completely different, including the bit-length of `int` and `long`. So the above explanation, although possibly interesting, is of no practical value. Had you simply included the correct header and thereby told the compiler the real return type of `strtol`, you would have gotten the output you expected.